# Ссылки на элементы массива

Tags: массивы, php, ссылки

Вот попалась задачка:

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($a as &$v){
 $v = $v + 1;
}
foreach ($a as $v){
 echo $v." ";
}
```

Скрипт выдает 2,3,3. Хоть убей, не могу сообразить почему? Ведь print_r($a) выдаст 2,3,4 после первого цикла

Comment: да, действительно странно откуда там запятые :)

Comment: http://ideone.com/V8zB49#view_edit_box print_r  выдает

    Array
    (
       [0] => 2
       [1] => 3
       [2] => 3
    )

Comment: @eicto, думаю автор сделал дамп до второго цикла

Comment: @xEdelweiss, да чистая правда, вопрос сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть в том, что `$v` у вас является ссылкой на последний элемент массива даже во время второго прохода. И каждую итерацию последнему значению присваивается значение текущего элемента. Ну а на момент, когда вы дошли до конца, последнее значение равно предпоследнему :)

Чтобы этого избежать, сделайте `unset($v)` сразу после того, как отработал первый цикл. Это разорвет связь.

Посмотрите на этот пример:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach ($a as &$v){
 $v = $v + 1;
}

foreach ($a as $key => $v){
    echo 'текущий = '.$v.'<br />';
    echo 'последний = '. $a[count($a)-1].'<hr />';
}
```

Получите:

```
текущий = 2
последний = 2
--
текущий = 3
последний = 3
--
текущий = 4
последний = 4
--
текущий = 5
последний = 5
--
текущий = 5
последний = 5
```

Подробности можно почитать тут: [References and foreach](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/141-References-and-foreach.html)

Comment: я бы ещё добавил, что можно просто unset($v) сделать чтобы он больше не был ссылкой http://ideone.com/3sry7c#view_edit_box

Comment: @eicto, да, я до того как задать вопрос так и сделал, но это не подсказало мне причину такого поведения

Comment: @eicto, да, согласен. Я как раз добавил ``unset()``